# Atmega-328 as an alternative to the Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, pcb, atmega

As I am building on, every day I learn something new. Today I learned that I really don't need a full-size Arduino (Uno/Nano.) All I need is an ATmega328(/p) chip microcontroller.

At this point, I started looking up basics like how to program it. I came across this tutorial on youtube which demonstrated it. The guy used this setup to simulate an Arduino UNO.

[image]

**Note:** My eventual goal is to get a custom PCB.

This led me to wonder

1. Will I have to use this whole setup for the chip (Atmega 328) to work as a replacement for the Arduino?
2. If the answer to the above question is yes, is there any other version of Arduino which I could/should use instead? I am considering another version of Arduino instead of including the above setup on my custom PCB because having all this on the PCB might add to the complexity of the design and push me to have a multiple layered PCB. If I use an Arduino, its components will in a way be on a different layer.

Comment: Your second question is not clear. You also need a push button on pin 1 for reset. A small and simple arduino is the pro mini. If you need USB, then the nano. Also, you don't need the crystal if you use the internal 8MHz oscillator.

Comment: You can remove everything. And to program you can use another Arduino, but I prefer to use a programmer. I use FTDI CHIP TTL-232D-5V

Answer (score 2):

1. This setup only for running uploaded program. Not included voltage regulator, USB to Serial part and many component. Atleast, I recomment to design Serial port to debug or re-upload the program.
   Also, You can use Arduino promini schematic as reference which include power led, d13 led, some circuit for upload code with usb to serial and reset button. I have done many custom PCB based on Arduino. these component will help ypu develope and debug quit easily.
2. Depend on you IO, if you want very small circuit with less IO you can try Digispark Attiny85 Arduino competible.

Comment: Don’t forget the 100nF bypass caps on the power pins! What are these? Search out the zillions of forum posts where these were not added and there were problems. Then refer to the Uno schematic.